# Laravel 5.2: Enable laravel-debugbar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar


error:
Problem 1
- illuminate/session v7.9.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.9.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.9.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.8.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.8.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.7.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.7.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.6.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.6.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.6.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.5.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.5.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.5.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.4.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.3.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.2.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.2.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.2.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.14.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.14.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.13.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.12.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.11.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.10.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.10.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.10.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.10.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.1.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.1.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.1.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.1.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.8 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.7 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.6 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.5 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.4 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.3 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.2 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v7.0.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.8.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.7.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.6.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.6.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.6.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.5.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.5.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.5.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.4.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.3.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.9 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.8 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.7 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.6 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.5 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.18 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.17 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.16 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.15 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.14 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.13 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.12 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.11 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.10 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.18.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.17.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.17.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.16.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.15.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.15.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.14.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.13.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.13.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.12.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.11.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.10.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.0.4 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.0.3 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.0.2 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.0.1 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v6.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.36 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.35 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.34 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.33 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.32 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.31 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.30 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.29 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.8.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.7.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.9 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.8 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.7 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.6 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.5 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.4 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.39 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.38 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.37 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.36 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.35 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.34 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.33 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.32 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.31 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.30 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.29 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.28 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.27 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.26 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.25 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.24 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.23 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.22 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.21 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.20 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.2 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.16 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.15 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.14 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.13 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.12 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.11 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.10 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.1 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session v5.6.0 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session 5.7.19 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session 5.7.18 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/session 5.7.17 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (7.0.33) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.2.45
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
- barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v3.3.3 requires illuminate/session ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.
```

39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.2
9, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.
23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8
.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6
.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0
, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.
1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v3.3.2 requires illuminate/session ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.
39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.2
9, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.
23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8
.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6
.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0
, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.
1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v3.3.1 requires illuminate/session ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.
39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.2
9, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.
23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8
.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6
.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0
, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.
1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v3.3.0 requires illuminate/session ^5.5|^6|^7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/session[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.
39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.2
9, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.
23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8
.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6
.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0
, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.
1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - don't install illuminate/session v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.2.45, required as 5.2.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.2.45].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ^3.3 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.2, v3.3.3].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What information have you gained from reading that error message?

Answer (score 5):

You are using `php 7.0.33` but one of laravel debugbar dependencies requires `php ^7.2.5` since you are using laravel 5.2 you can try to install your suitable version which is 3.2.5 I believe
`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:3.2.5`
if that didn't work try
`composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:3.2.0`