# Could Not Install Package gloudemans/shoppingcart

Tags: php, html, laravel, xampp

I am trying to install, i use laravel 8.3 version

composer require gloudemans/shoppingcart

but it came an error like this :

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
- gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., 5.7.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

could somebody solve my problems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2: Enable laravel-debugbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274073/laravel-5-2-enable-laravel-debugbar)

Answer (score 0):

As from the error, version 2.6 of gloudemans/shoppingcart doesn't support Laravel 8. The latest it supports is Laravel 5.7.

If you visit its [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/gloudemans/shoppingcart#2.6.0) page, it lists the illuminate/support (i.e. Laravel) versions it supports.